# Get data and total data using one query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have documents like this:

```
[
        {
          productName: 'Soap',
          qty: 12
        },
        {
          productName: 'Apple',
          qty: 14
        },
        ........
]
```

If I want to get the total data, I used this query:

```
Model
   .find({condition})
   .count();
```

If I want to get the data with pagination, I used this query:

```
Model
   .find({condition})
   .skip(..)
   .limit(..);
```

Is it possible to get total data and the data with only one query?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make use of the MongoDB's aggregate framework for this.

```
db.kim1.aggregate( [
{
"$match" : {
"productName" : "orange"
}
},
{
"$group" : {
"_id" : null,
"my_documents" : {
"$push" : {
"_id" : "$_id",
"productName" : "$productName",
"qty" : "$qty"
}
},
"docCount" : {
"$sum" : 1
}
}
},
{
"$project" : {
"_id" : 0,
"my_documents" : 1,
"total" : "$docCount"
}
}
] )
```

i created the following documents 
[image]

and once i execute the above query i get the following output:

[image]